# Add Calendar Event via Promotional Email onGoogle and iCal

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api, icalendar

In a promotional email, I have added links to create an event on Google Calendar and iCal (iOS calendar). I found out that I can create the Google Calendar event using the following URL format

> http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&dates=20200515T000000Z/20200515T010000Z&location=My_Location&trp=false&text=Event_Title&details=Event_Details

Is there a way to create the Calendar event on iCal or iCloud using a URL and passing data via query string parameters?

Comment: It's not possible without user interaction, so what about creating a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) with Apps Script that will request to insert an event?

Comment: I can create the event in Google Calendar using the above-mentioned URL but could not found for iCal

Answer (score 1):

As [@jescanellas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7500904/jescanellas) mentioned, I don't think that's possible, but you can send an .ics file containing info for that event in an email. Upon clicking on the file it'd be added to users iOs Calendar.

Example event:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:19970610T172345Z-AF23B2@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970610T172345Z
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T040000Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

You can find more about it here [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545).